# Subir imagen en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas, estoy un poco bastante oxidado en PHP así que, en plena fase de refrescar conceptos, estoy haciendo un formulario para subir imagenes a una BD (el nombre y la ruta, realmente) y luego, en caso de que dicha imagen se encuentre en la carpeta del servidor especificada en la ruta, mostrarla por pantalla.

El código que realiza la inserción de datos es éste:

```
if ($_POST['enviar']) {
$nombre = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$nombrer = strtolower($_REQUEST['nombre']);
$origen= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "img/" . $nombrer . ".jpg";
copy ($origen,$destino);
$subida = mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO imagenes VALUES ('". $nombre ."','" . $destino . "')");   
if (@mysqli_query($conexion,$subida)) {
    echo "La foto se ha subido con éxito";
}
```

La inserción de datos en la tabla se efectúa correctamente, el problema lo estoy teniendo a la hora de copiar el archivo que subo, la imagen, a la carpeta /img del servidor. Hasta donde recuerdo, eso se hacía empleando la función copy, a la que le pasaba como parámetros la URL de origen en /tmp y la de destino.

He probado a imprimir el resultado de la variable $origen y me devuelve una ruta tipo:

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php719F.tmp
```

Al acceder a esa carpeta me encuentro con que ese archivo no existe... ¿Puede ser esa la base del problema?

Comment: Por Dios, basta de consultas armadas concatenando valores pasados en el request, eso es peligrosisimo, un atacante te puede ver/alterar/borrar la base de datos (ver sql injection attacks). http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que no estas subiendo la imagen al servidor, replique tu entorno de la tematica  y le hice unas modificaciones minimas y **si funciona** ; recuerda que $origen= $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']; debe ser igual al name de tu input tipo file;

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="foto_post.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table width="350" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#000000">
                <tr>
                    <td height="85" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <div align="center">
                            <input name="imagen" type="file" maxlength="150">
                            <br><br>                                     
                            <input type="submit" value="Agregar" name="enviar" style="cursor: pointer">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**foto_post.php**

```
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");

$nombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$nombrer = strtolower($nombre);
$cd=$_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
$ruta = "img/" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$destino = "img/".$nombrer;
$resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"], $ruta);

if (!empty($resultado)){

                @mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO fotos VALUES ('". $nombre."','" . $destino . "')"); 
                echo "el archivo ha sido movido exitosamente";

                }else{

                    echo "Error al subir el archivo";

                    }
?>
```

**conexion.php**

```
<?php

    $hostname_cn = "localhost";
    $database_cn = "imagen";
    $username_cn = "root";
    $password_cn = "";
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_cn, $username_cn, $password_cn,$database_cn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esta es la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el resultado cuando sube la foto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres podrias poner tu input que recupera el nombre de la foto, Yo no lo puse porque no me parecio asi, Me parece que se deberia quedar con su nombre del  file de subida.

Answer (score 1):

Este es el código que uso yo. El nombre de "portada", es el nombre de mi input

```
if (!isset($_POST['portada'])){
        $nombre_archivo =$_FILES['portada']['name'];
        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['portada']['type'];
        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['portada']['size'];
        $archivo= $_FILES['portada']['tmp_name'];
    } else{
        $nombre_archivo="";
    }

    if ($nombre_archivo!="")
    {
        //Limitar el tipo de archivo y el tamaño    
        if (!((strpos($tipo_archivo, "gif") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "jpeg") || strpos($tipo_archivo, "png")) && ($tamano_archivo  < 50000000))) 
        {
            echo "El tamaño de los archivos no es correcta. <br><br><table><tr><td><li>Se permiten archivos de 5 Mb máximo.</td></tr></table>";
        }
        else
        {
            $file = $_FILES['portada']['name'];
            $res = explode(".", $nombre_archivo);
            $extension = $res[count($res)-1];
            $nombre= date("YmdHis")."." . $extension; //renombrarlo como nosotros queremos
            $dirtemp = "../../upload/temp/".$nombre."";//Directorio temporaral para subir el fichero

            if (is_uploaded_file($_POST['portada']['tmp_name'])) {
                copy($_FILES['portada']['tmp_name'], $dirtemp);

                unlink($dirtemp); //Borrar el fichero temporal
               }
            else
            {
                echo "Ocurrió algún error al subir el fichero. No pudo guardarse.";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: como estableces la ruta en que se cargaran tus archivos temp ? es que yo vi en mi php.init que la que me muestra es upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp\tmp", como hago uso de esa ruta, suponiendo que tengo mi proyecto en htdocs de xampp

Comment: $dirtemp = "../../upload/temp/".$nombre."";. Con esta instruccion se lo asigno. Normalmente siempre creo la caepeta upload en todos mis proyectos

Answer (score 0):

este metodo es con ajax y php

```
 function UploadImage() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var File = $("#FilesForm")[0].files[0];
  var FileName = $("#FilesForm")[0].files[0].name;
  formData.append("I", File);

  $.ajax({
    url: "php/UploadFile_controller.php",
    type: "Post",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (r) {
          alert(r);   
    },
    error: function (e) {
          alert(e);
    },
  });
  return false;
}
```

```
<?php
class UploadImage
{
    public static function Upload()
    {
        try {
            //Definir formato, tambien puedes agregar otra extenciones si quieres
            $format = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "svg");

            //ubicacion en el archivo raiz donde se guarda la imagen
            $upload = "../upload/";

            //saber el nombre del archivo
            $File = $_FILES['I']['name'];

            //nombre temporal del fichero
            $tmp = ($_FILES['I']['tmp_name']);

            //concatenas el nombre completo
            $save =  $upload . $File;

            //saber la extencion del archivo
            $extension = pathinfo($File, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            //validacion del formato del arvhibo
            if (!in_array($extension, $format)) {
                //alerta para saber que no es un formato correspondiente
                echo "It is not the correct format.";
            } else {
                //copia el archivo al nodo raiz
                move_uploaded_file($tmp,  $save);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "An error has occurred: " . $e;
        }
    }
}
//ejecutar la funcion php
UploadImage::Upload();
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).